# RxJs map operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I don't understand how to solve an issue in the following scenario:

```
getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(this.postsUrl).pipe(
      tap(() => console.log('fetched posts')),
      catchError(this.handleError<Post[]>('getPosts', []))
    );
  }
```

.......

```
export const mapYearWeek = (post: Post): Post => {
  post.time = `
  ${moment(parseInt(post.time)).year()}
  -${moment(parseInt(post.time)).week()}
  `;
  return post;
};
```

.........

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postService
      .getPosts()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(res => res.map(mapYearWeek(post: Post))),  
        tap((res) => console.log(res)),
        groupBy((post: Post) => post.time),
        mergeMap((group) => group.pipe(toArray())),
        tap((res) => console.log(res))
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

I'm getting error with mapYearweek func:

> Argument of type 'Post' is not assignable to parameter of type
> '(value: Post, index: number, array: Post[]) => unknown'.   Type
> 'Post' provides no match for the signature '(value: Post, index:
> number, array: Post[]): unknown'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  mergeMap(res => res.map(mapYearWeek(post: Post))),
```

should be

```
  mergeMap(res => res.map(post => mapYearWeek(post))),
```

Comment: I solved, actually it could be mergeMap(res => res.map(post => mapYearWeek)),

Comment: I think it could be just `mergeMap(res => res.map(mapYearWeek)),`